# Powerpoint hyperlink GET request to Node Express API launches 3 calls

Tags: node.js, rest, express, powerpoint

I have a node.js express REST API wich runs some logic in a GET endpoint of a controller.

When i type the url in the browser all looks good. Only one request and  the logic runs one time:

GET /api/users/ppt/confirm 200 77ms

Message sent: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3n5vdG0v13zghfL

For prototyping/meeting purposes i need to run the request from a powerpoint hyperlink. The result is that when i click the hyperlink from a ppt button my server runs the controller 3 times:

HEAD /api/users/ppt/confirm 200 7ms

GET /api/users/ppt/confirm 200 6ms

GET /api/users/ppt/confirm 200 6ms

Message sent: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3n5vnz477wzghfL

Message sent: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3n5vnz67mpzghfN

Message sent: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3n5vp03JsKzghfR

The HEAD one makes me suspect but i really dont know what is happening.

How can i fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't explain the 3 one....  The first could be a request for info, second could be the download.  I know MS does some goofy security things when u click links within their app.  But I would expect 2 calls (head, get) not a third.

Comment: Check out this link it explains it: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71112/make-server-force-excel-to-hand-over-hyperlink-to-browser-without-trying-to-load

Comment: Great info @Nix but how can i block the 2 first requests and only let pass the "true browser" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  solve the problem with an if statement inside the controller:

```
/*You can use any other request-headers based condition but this one works
 for me */

if(req.headers['user-agent'].split(' ')[0] == "Mozilla/5.0"){

  //do stuff
}
else{
  res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
  res.write("Hi PowerPoint");  
  res.end(); 
  return;
}
```